# How to: compare command output to text file with bash

Tags: linux, bash, diff, ls

I'm trying to compare the output of the command

```
`ls -l directory`
```

with a file that I've created using the same command. (I'm trying a poor man's way of making sure no files have been modified.)

The trouble is, I don't know how to `diff` the output of the `ls` command with the file that I've created. I've tried the following and each time it doesn't work

```
diff file.ls <(ls -l directory)
ls -l directory | xargs diff file.ls
ls -l directory | diff file.ls
diff file.ls < `ls -l directory`
```

What is the magic command to compare the output of `ls` to a file that I've already saved?

Comment: What do you mean by __doesn't work__?  Does the system hang, do you see a BSOD, do you experience thunder & lightning, what?

Comment: Moreover, don't [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: What was the problem with `diff file.ls <(ls -l directory)`?

Comment: To just see if they're different: `if diff -q f1 f2; then echo same; fi`

Comment: @thatotherguy Oops. The output of `diff file.ls <(ls -l directory)` was blank because there was no difference. **<embarrassed>**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer (for posterity) is to do the following

```
diff file.ls <(ls -l directory)
```

When I did this previously, the output was blank. I thought I had done it wrong; in actuality there was no difference between the contents of the directory and my file.

**<\facepalm>**

Comment: For the record, you can also do it this way: `ls -l | diff - file.ls`. I don't think that's significantly different in efficiency, but it is more portable to shells other than `bash`...

Comment: @twalberg I would go with `ls -l | diff file.ls -` so I could keep left/right straight in my head.

Comment: @robert I will accept this answer. StackOverflow makes me wait two days before I accept my own answer.

Answer (score 2):

`diff` is easiest when you compare files.

```
$ ls $DIR > original.ls
do some stuff
$ ls $DIR > new.ls
$ diff original.ls new.ls
```